# How to intuitively understand definite integral formulas?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have studied that

$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\, dx = 2\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$ if $f(x)$ is an even function

and

$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\, dx = 0$ if $f(x)$ is an odd function

---

similarly

$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx$ = $2\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$ if f(x) is an even function

and

$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx$ = $0$ if f(x) is an odd function

---

But how to intuitively understand the reason why these formulas are so framed?

Comment: The last two formulas are false in general. Are you assuming that $f$ is $2a$-periodic?

Comment: The last two formulas are incorrect; consider $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ and $a = \pi/2$; these are counterexamples.

Comment: The third and fourth formulas aren't correct.  Consider the counter examples (with $a=1$) $$f_1(x)=\begin{cases}1&|x|\leq1\\0&|x|>1\end{cases}$$$$f_2(x)=x$$

Comment: But for the first two, look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbwJOQnT1eM This is one of those results which is very intuitive once a picture is drawn (watch from 7 mins onwards)

Comment: Then why I am able to solve $\int_{0}^{π} cos^5x dx$ with the last formula?
It gives me correct ans $0$

Comment: Because cosine is periodic with period $4a=2\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're being told in comments, the final two statements are not true.  But consider an even function.

[image]

Here, the areas in the first and second quadrant mirror each other, so the sum of the red and blue areas is equal to twice the blue area.

Similarly for an odd function.

[image]

Now the red and blue areas cancel each other out, because they are reflected across the x-axis as well as the y-axis.  So here, the total integral is $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)